# JavaScript in HTML - Increasing time gradually by clicking on img

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a problem with increasing the time of appearance of a image gradually by clicking on it with the mouse. I hope you all could take a look and advise me on that.

Here is the code:

```
function randomTime(min, max) {
    return Math.round(max);
}

function randomHole(mines) {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * mines.length);
    const mine = mines[idx];
    if (mine === lastHole) {
        return randomHole(mines);
    }
    lastHole = mine;
    return mine;
}// show gold car

function appear() {
    const time = randomTime(2000, 500);
    const mine = randomHole(mines);
    mine.classList.add('up');
    setTimeout(() => {
        mine.classList.remove('up');
        if (!timeUp) appear();
    }, time);
}
```

I am overwhelmed with things to do and it might be the case I can not figure it out... Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Please explain in more detail.  What do you mean "increasing the time of appearance of a image"?

Comment: Im creating a game which will display a image in 6 random location and everytime the user clicks on the img it will increase the score by 1. Overall I have the img and everything working properly but I just want to show the img faster once the user clicks on it so it becomes faster and harder to catch each time. I will probably create a function to reset the speed once the user feels like not catching the img anymore back to normal default speed. But yeah, thats what I wont from now, gradually increase de speed OnClick each time...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you need fix this line:

```
return Math.round(max);
```

Because function just round max value

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: So you can simply do something like this `return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;`

Comment: I did this before and gave me just random time between my max and min values... I need it to increase from min(2000ms) to max(500ms) everytime the user clicks on the img so it gets harder

Comment: You can try to pass  in this function last  time  and max and do some thing like this:
`function randomTime(last, max) {
    return (max - last) / 2 + last;
}`

Comment: I actually did: `return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);` and gave me random time. by the way

Comment: Please see my suggestion above. Maybe it will useful for you

Comment: Still not working, but I appreciate your time and effort @Kasabucki